# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *__strong *' to parameter of type 'NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable'

Tags: objective-c, pointers, type-conversion, incompatibletypeerror

I am facing this warning in my project. Welcome to suggestions.. and Thanks :).

This is my code :

```
NSString *profile = @"Profile";
NSData *data = [profile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `propertyListWithData:options:format:error:`. Note the data type for the `error` parameter. Now look at how you declared your `error` variable.

The line:

```
NSString *error;
```

needs to be:

```
NSError *error;
```

Comment: warning gone. Thanks rmaddy

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issues.

Comment: Sure I accepted.. New in stack overflow.. Thanks :)